# Hide resources in iOS framework

Tags: xcode, ios8, frameworks, resources, ios9

I am developing Universal iOS framework using this [guide](https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/ios-9-universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks/).
How to hide images inside framework from other developers?

Also, I am not sure, do we need Info.plist file inside framework?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find out if it's possible to hide images in a framework?

Comment: See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by [encrypt](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) the resources. I am not sure, that is the best way to resolve, but it works in my case.
[Here](https://github.com/Hantok/ResourceEncrypter) is a simple OS X app that encrypt files before adding it to the framework.

Code for decrypt:

```
NSError* error;
NSData* encryptedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData* decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                                  withPassword:@"SAMPLE-KEY"
                                         error:&error];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:decryptedData];
```

`

Code for encrypt:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSError* error;
NSData* encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                  withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                      password:@"SAMPLE-KEY"
                                         error:&error];
[encryptedData writeToFile:encryptedFilePath atomically:YES];
```